# How do I make a transaction

Tags: transactions, multi-signature, raw-transaction

I want to make a multisig transaction but dont how to do it. I am using this site: coinb.in

And what is Txin or N that it also can be called.

Comment: I recently found coinb.in returned an error with their certificate meaning it may be unsafe to use the site to utilize any security sensitive (private key related) functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The certificates have been fixed and SSL/HTTPs is working properly now.

TXID referrers to the transaction ID

N referrers to which input you want to use from that transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! You're the administrator of coinb.in, right?